# How can I integrate googleaccounts into my android app? like facebook getprofile information and accesstoken etc

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-account

how to integrate google accounts my android applications like facebook getting the accesstoken and getting profile informations and etc

actually I am used to develope the based on this link

http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/09/google-account-integration-in-android.html

but this is not correct way how integrate googleaccounts sdk into my android applications

Comment: you need to use play services. The best resources here - https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Comment: i tried above link i didnot get proper result is there any sample anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have give you git hub repository URL in this repository basically gmail authentication after successfully authentication you can access profile information like profile image, name etc hope you requirement is full fill if not you can ask with out any hesitation, i give you another optimal solution.
Here's [a link](https://github.com/ShehryarAhmed/GmailAuthFirebase)